# Exchange mailbox stopped syncing on mobile - work with a weird behavior

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2016, activesync

- Workaround found -

I'm encountering a weird issue on Exchange Server 2016 on premise.

2 users of my Active Directory base stopped receiving new email on mobile (Outlook Android client), but email are OK in OWA or Outlook PC client.

I did the account removal / add again for one of the user and it began working again after that. The second account is still stuck : when we add the account, wee see email up to a specific date then new one aren't there.

I checked Activesync, it seems to be working.

The weird part is :

user1@domain.fr domain\user and his password 
No sync of the last emails on mobile

I created a second user and mailbox :user2@domain.fr domain\user2 and his password

When I connect to the mailbox2@domain.fr using the first user creditentials (user1), I have the content of the mailbox1, with the last emails, and the sync working...

I don't know where it came from.

It seems to have appeared a few day the new year bug, 4 days after I applied the powershell script.

I tried deleting user1 and his mailbox, recreated it, and the glitch is still there.

Do anyone encountered this, or have any clues ?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

No, there was no policy.I found a way to bypass this error : the mailbox have 2 domain name alias on the Exchange server : 1 in @domain.local and another one in @domain.fr I used the .local to log in to the mailbox, and it work fine.Mail are sent using the .fr extension, despite .local showing in the app, because .fr are set as default domain.I don't know where this issue came from, but using this workaround fix it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is caused by mobile mail client, instead of mailbox itself.
Is the mobile iPhone or Android? Did you use built-in mail app or Outlook for mobile app?

You create the new user and mailbox: user2, is it have any relationship with user1?

“I tried deleting user1 and his mailbox, recreated it, and the glitch is still there.” Did you use the same email address?

I suggest you do the followings:

1. Restart mobile device
2. Configure the new mailbox in another mobile device
3. Use Outlook app instead of built-in mail client

Comment: The issue is not caused by the client.
It does the same, on any Android / iOS phone, using the Outlook app or the embedded mail client. There is no relation between user1 and user2, it's the weirdeist part, if you open mailbox2 with user1 creditentials, you get user1 mail working. Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Are you the admin for Exchange server?
Did you configure any mobile policy or access rule which may block this mailbox? 
Use the Get- Get-MobileDeviceMailboxPolicy cmdlet to retrieve the Mobile Device mailbox policy settings for a specific Mobile Device mailbox policy.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mobiledevicemailboxpolicy?view=exchange-ps